# Geoserver: How do Coverage Stores work?

Tags: geoserver, rest

I'm working on a project at work to download imagery from else where and add it to geoserver. I have no experience in GIS, nonetheless geoserver. I've been hunting through the REST api for 2.0.X of Geoserver and can create workspaces and empty coverage stores. I get that coverage stores hold raster graphics, but is it one-to-one or do they share a special relation by being in the same store? What's the URL and method (PUT, POST, etc) to add a tiff to a coverage store?

Comment: http://svn.codehaus.org/geoserver/branches/1.7.x/src/extension/restconfig/scripts/coveragestores.sh

Answer (score 3):

Well the model for raster data in geoserver is that a coverage store can contain multiple coverages. But that said in general, in that 2.0.x version the relationship is 1-1. There is currently work going to support coverages that have the notion of another dimension (like time), at which time you will start to see geoserver support multiple coverages for a single coverage store.

Mapperz provided a good link with some examples. There is also a good reference in the user guide:

http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/restconfig/rest-config-examples/rest-config-examples-curl.html#uploading-a-shapefile

It is for shapefile but for geotiff it is more or less the same, just change shp -> geotiff accordingly, as the examples show.

Comment: I suppose the file has to be a zip? I'm writing a service to download imagery from a 3rd party service and import directly into geoserver and if it's not necessary to zip, then I would like to avoid that step. What content type would it be if a skip zipping (if possible). Also, side note, what kind of names are coverage stores given? I am completely new to geoserver standards...

Comment: Broken link: now there is an *Examples* section in the docs which points to several, indeed, examples: https://docs.geoserver.org/maintain/en/user/rest/index.html#examples

Answer (score 1):

you can use this curl which creates layers in a hedge shop and if there is no hedge shop creates it

`curl -v -u admin:geoserver -XPUT -H "Content-type: text/plain" -d "File location" "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/HereWorkspaceName/coveragestores/HereCoverageName/external.geotiff?configure=first&coverageName=HereCoverageName"`

Answer (score 0):

We need to take 2 actions: a post and a put request.

first of all, you should create a coverage store with a post request using curl like the below in CMD:

```
curl -u admin:geoserver -v -XPOST -H "Content-Type: application/xml" -d "<coverageStore><name>my_store</name><workspace>cite</workspace><enabled>true</enabled></coverageStore>" http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/cite/coveragestores
```

then you need to add your raster to the store with a put request:

```
curl -u admin:geoserver -v -XPUT -H "Content-Type: text/plain" -d "file:/C:/MYORTHO.tif" http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/cite/coveragestores/my_store/external.geotiff?configure=first\&coverageName=my_store
```

after executing the above command, you can see that the raster is created and published.

if you're using postman, you can extract and copy the body of the request and paste it to the body section in postman as XML.